# is it possible to delete the admin user in wazuh manager dashboard

Tags: wazuh

I try to delete the admin user in wazuh but i did not find any proper documentation if anybody know about this solution pls let me know

Is it possible to delete the admin user in wazuh manager dashboard

Answer (score 0):

The removal of the administrator user from a system is generally not a good practice, keep in mind that the **admin** user is a user intended to manage and control security options that a normal user should not access and that in case there is any problem, to have access with which to be able to fix certain things.

What is the reason for wanting to remove it? If what you are concerned about is the password of said user, for example, as in the case of the OVA in which the default is user **admin** and password **admin**, this password can be modified as indicated in the following documentation:

- https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/securing-wazuh/wazuh-indexer.html